# Get values in a dict to not update. Python 3.6.9

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I would like to fill a dict with lists. But it seems like the dict keeps updating the values i pass in.
I am currently doing something like this:

```
Dict=dict()
lst = list()
for i in range(10):
    lst.append(i)
    Dict[f'{i}']=lst
```

and would like to obtain `Dict={'0': [0], 1: [1,2], ... }`

but I get `Dict={'0': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], '1': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], ...}`

Is there a nice way to get around this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`Dict[f'{i}']=lst` inserts the exact same list object over and over again, because assignment generally *doesn't copy* objects. `lst.append(i)` modifies that *one* list object. So your dictionary ends up containing lots of pointers to the same list.

To insert a different object each time, copy the current list:

```
Dict[f'{i}']=lst.copy()
# or Dict[str(i)] = lst.copy()
```